# How to add a new match/mapping for an existing language?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Thanks to an extension ([*Caddyfile Syntax*](https://github.com/Zamerick/vscode-caddyfile-syntax), [*Caddyfile Support*](https://github.com/matthewpi/vscode-caddyfile-support)) I have highlighting for [`Caddyfile`](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile). Installing the extensions also mapped `Caddyfile` files with the relevant syntax highlighting rules.

I now would like to also have the same mapping for `caddy.conf` files.

According to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers), I should add an `alias` for `caddy.conf` so that it is handled the same way as `Caddyfile`.

The problem is that I do not know where to add this information in `settings.json`.

I had a look for anything "caddy" in `defaultSettings.json` but I do not see any structure that would match th eone in the documentation. Namely, I only see

```
    // Configure settings to be overridden for the caddyfile language.
    "[caddyfile]":  {
        "editor.insertSpaces": false,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
```

What I am looking for should more look like (according to the documentation above)

```
 "languages": [{
        "id": "java",
        "extensions": [ ".java", ".jav" ],
        "aliases": [ "Java", "java" ]
    }]
```

So in practical terms - where in `setting.json` should I add the `alias` (or possibly a new mapping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `settings.json`:

```json
"files.associations": {
  "*.conf": "caddyfile"
}
```

Alternatively, you can invoke the `workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode` command (`Ctrl+K M` by default, also works by clicking the language label in the status bar) and select the language you want. This is probably preferable if you might have files with the same extension, but different syntax.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that the way to go was via `alias` but indeed simply adding this works great.